# http response body always empty or undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, express, docker-compose

I'm making a get call from a nodejs service inside a docker container to an api in another container with the `request` module they're all managed with docker-compose and every time no matter what i try the response body is always either empty or undefined.

when i make the call with postman i get the response body i want.

i have the two as services defined in my `docker-compose.yaml` so instead of using `localhost` and the port number i use the service's name as a host.

here is the call:

```
 Request.find({$and : [{status : 'Delivered'},
    {pickup : req.params.location}]})
    .then(requests => {
        var resultRequests = requests.forEach( (request) => {
            request.get('http://spare_web:3080/spares/warehouse/'+request.spareSerial, function(err, response, body) {
                console.log(response.statusCode); // 200
                console.log(response.headers['content-type']); // 'application/json'
                console.log(body);//it returns '{"data":[]}' and when i change it to body[0] it returns '{'
                console.log(err);
              });



        })

        res.send({data : requests});
    })
```

and here is the api:

```
exports.findBySerial = (req, res) => {
    Spare.find({serial : req.params.serial })
    .then(spares => {
        res.send(spares);
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send({
            message: err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving spares."
        });
    });
};
```

note the the api's service's name is `spare_web` and it's running on port `3080` the first service is running on `3088`.

the weird thing about it is that the status code is always `200 OK` and the `err` message is always null so that means it actually makes the connection but why does it always return and empty response body?

EDIT: after sandboxing the controller and trying to get just about anything from the endpoint in post man i found out that after getting the response body and sending it with `res.send` i receive an empty object as `text/html` upon checking the headers in postman although they are sent as `application/json`

Comment: have you checked your connection string? Try hardcoding the `container` value just for a test and make a request this way.

Comment: well as i said in my question i made the request with postman outside of the container on `localhost:3080` and it returned the desired response body inside the container i can only use the service's name as a host

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending the data, `res.send({ data: requests })`, before any of the requests have finished, as they are asynchronous.

Perhaps you could use promises - something like this:

```
Request
  .find({ $and: [{ status: 'Delivered' }, { pickup: req.params.location }]})
  .then(docs => {
    var promises = docs
      .map(doc => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          request.get('http://spare_web:3080/spares/warehouse/' + doc.spareSerial, function(err, response, body) {
            if (err) reject(err);
            resolve(body);
          });
        });
      });

    Promise.all(promises)
      .then(spares => {
        console.log(spares)

        // Do something with spares
        res.send({ data: ... });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        // Handle error
      });
  });
```

Comment: it returns `[ '{"data":[]}' ]` on `console.log(spares)`